# Docker on Windows 10 Pro: error file conflict when building new Jekyll site

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, jekyll, jekyll-theme

I am using **PowerShell on Windows 10 Pro** and have installed **Docker version** **18.03.1-ce**.

I CD into a local directory where I want to edit a set of config files to build my Jekyll webpage. I ran the following command:

```
docker run -e JEKYLL_NEW=true -p 80:4000 -v ${pwd}:/site bretfisher/jekyll-serve
```

and the the following message:

```
NOTE: making new jekyll site!
          Conflict: /site exists and is not empty.
                    Ensure /site is empty or else try again with `--force` to proceed and overwrite any files.
```

If I use the `--force` flag inside the call above it tells me unknown flag. Anyone has any idea how to fix this and successfully build a jekyll container linked to my local directory of files to be able to edit and preview on `localhost` in the browser before pushing it into production?

Answer (score 2):

Pay close attention to the steps in the [Jekyll quick start](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/). In step 3, Jekyll creates the directory for your web site. The error message is telling you that there's already an existing `site` directory with files in it, so Jekyll quits rather than overwrite existing files. If you delete the contents of that directory or move them elsewhere, your `jekyll new` command can proceed.

You might try picking a different site name, by the way. Jekyll creates its own `_site` directory where it puts the built HTML files for your site. You're asking for confusion when you have a `site/_site` directory.